# Barnes Hut algorithm performance and error bounds

Tags: numerical-methods, mathematical-physics, computational-complexity

Consider $N$ particles with massa $m$ spaced out on a $\Omega = [0,1]^2$. The force acting on each particle reads $$F_i = \sum_j C\frac{m_i m_j}{r_{ij}^2}$$ for some constant $C$. The problem here is that we would need to do $O(N^2)$ calculations to compute it fully (since there are $N$ forces to calculate each containing a sum over $N-1$ elements).

Therefore I try to use some handy approximation that will reduce the computational complexity. We subdivide the particles into a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) data structure in order to use [Barnes - Hut algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes%E2%80%93Hut_simulation) ([alternative](http://arborjs.org/docs/barnes-hut)) on the problem. 
All the sources I see state the complexity to be $O(N \log N)$ but I am unable to find any kind of proof for this statement. Also it seems a wrong statement in general - BH has a free parameter $\theta$ which should be included in the analysis because if $\theta = 0$ the complexity is $O(N^2)$.

I'd like to have an (derivation of) expression (or at least a sketch of a derivation) for the complexity as a function of $N$ and $\theta$. Also some bound on error of the approximation as a function of these two variables would be nice to have for case $m_i = 1$ for all $i$ and for case $m_i = \pm 1$ distributed evenly.

Comment: I have not carried out a proper analysis, but intuitively the *asymptotic* complexity should be the same for all $\theta > 0$. The choice of $\theta$ just affects the constant factor and determines how large the system needs to be for the asymptotic scaling to become relevant.

Comment: I agree with this intuition. Problem is, I have only a very abstract idea on how such analyse should be carried out. The actual analysis would help me lots with the conceptual understanding of handling such type problems. And also it would solve this very problem - which is also very nice :)

Answer (score 2):

Asymptotics often ignore parameters - it's wrong to assume an asymptotic is uniform in all parameters by default.

For masses with consistent signs the multiplicative error is quadratic in $\theta.$ So if the estimate for $F_i$ is $F_i'$ then $F_i'/F_i$ will lie in $[1-c\theta^2,1+c\theta^2],$ for some absolute constant $c$ (and $0<\theta<1/2$ say). By scaling it suffices to look at the error of estimating the sum of $f(x)=1/|x|^2$ for particles with center of mass $(1,0,0)$ and within distance $O(\theta).$ By Taylor series each value is $f(1,0,0)+(x-(1,0,0))\cdot (\nabla f)(1,0,0)+O(|x-(1,0,0)|^2).$ The linear term cancels out because we're using the center of mass (monopole approximation). So the multiplicative error is bounded by $O(\theta^2).$ (I suspect there's a corresponding lower bound given by a uniform distribution.)

For mixed mass signs my instinct is to say there's isn't a sensible a priori error bound - if the forces cancel, the error could be much larger than the actual value.

The $O(N\log N)$ in the Barnes-Hut paper comes from considering particles in a grid (at least as I read it - they just say uniformly distributed). Suppose the universe size is $S$ and any pair of particles are separated by at least $s.$ Consider running Barnes-Hut to calculate the force at a particle at position $x.$ Points at distance $r>0$ from $x$ will be put in a cube of radius at least $\tfrac{1}{100}\theta r$ (being sloppy about constant). So we can upper bound the number of cubes by integrating $(\tfrac{1}{100}\theta r)^{-3}$ over points at distance between $s$ and $S$ from $x.$ Integrating using spherical co-ordinates gives a bound of $O(\theta^{-3})\int^S_s 1/r=O(\theta^{-3}\log(S/s)).$ For a grid we can put $S=1$ and $s=1/N^{1/3}$ for example, giving a bound of $O(\theta^{-3}\log N)$ cubes, for each of the $N$ iterations.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is 4-year late but I hope it could be useful to somebody.

The parameter $\theta$ plays a role in the computation of the force, not in the construction of the tree. Therefore, it is only present in the expression that represents the complexity of the computation of the forces.

According to this paper: ["Load Balancing and Data Locality in Adaptive Hierarchical N-Body Methods: Barnes-Hut, Fast Multipole, and Radiosity"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0743731585710775) (See subsection 3.1.1):

- The complexity of the construction of the tree is: $\mathcal{O} (N \, log N)$
- The complexity of computing the centers of mass is: $\mathcal{O} (N)$
- The complexity of computing the forces is: $\mathcal{O} (\frac{1}{\theta^2} \, log N)$

---

The proof that the depth of the tree is $log(N)$ is preety easy:

At the deepest level $K$, you want the number of boxes to be approximately equal to the number of particles. And the total number of boxes that you have at level $K$ is either $4^K$ in 2D or $8^K$ in 3D.
Then, $8^K = N \implies K \,log(K)=log (N) \implies K= \frac{log(N)}{log(8)} = log_8(N) $

Finally, for each particle $N$, you will have to traverse $log_8(N)$ nodes. Therefore, the complexity of building the tree is: $N\,log_8(N)$.

Note: The complexity of building the tree is $N\,log_8(N)$ in 3D and $N\, log_4(N)$ in 2D. But more generally, we will avoid writing $N
\,log_8(N)$ and $N \,log_4(N)$ and simply write $N\,log (N)$.